# How to use UISplitViewController when is not the rootViewController?

Tags: ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode5.1

I have a navigation view controller with number of button in it.When I Press the button I want to segue to another view that is the DetailView of my UISplitViewController.The problem is that I can segue to the Detail View but it can't enter to master view - the UISplitViewController doesn't work.I understand that the problem is related to the fact that the SplitViewController is not the root view controller.How could I solve this problem? and where should i write the code for the answer?